# Automatically update Firefox OS wallpaper

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-os

I am working on an app that fetches an image from the daily image sites and sets it as a wallpaper on the Firefox OS device. However I am not able to find a way to automatically change the wallpaper. Is this possible? I found an activity to bring up the wallpaper picker, [here](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/23021724/how-can-i-change-the-wallpaper-on-a-firefox-os-device) but it presents a pick menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this is by creating a certified application, as you will need access to the settings database which is not exposed to 'normal' applications. So you can only distribute to developer devices. Anyway, the relevant code is here: https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia/blob/master/apps/settings/js/panels/display/wallpaper.js#L107